# Prevent admin from making orders for out of stock products

Tags: magento, grid

In Magneto 2.2, the admin can create orders at backend for products that are out of stock or disabled. It tells the admin that this product you choose is out of stock but allows him to complete the order.

How can I prevent this order from being made if the admin choose an out of stock product in the order or ordered a quantity for a product that doesn't have enough quantity?

In Catalog>Inventory I set to hide products that are out of stock and set backorder to NO. but this only applied at frontend only not at the backend.

I was given This Code by the help of Sohel Rana and HIren Kadivar but it is not complete:

Try following way:

app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid">
    <plugin name="SR_MagentoStackExchange::product_grid_create_order"
            type="SR\MagentoStackExchange\Plugin\Block\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" sortOrder="1"/>
   </type>
   </config>
```

app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/Plugin/Block/Sales/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoStackExchange\Plugin\Block\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search;

class Grid
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock
     */
    private $stockFilter;

    /**
     * Grid constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockFilter
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockFilter
    ) {
        $this->stockFilter = $stockFilter;
    }

    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $this->stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
        $proceed($collection);
    }
}
?>
```

This method didnt work fully (partial solution), Most of the products are configurable product. So for a simple product the out of stock product is hidden and the admin cant select it, this was done by the extension written above. But for configurable product the admin can still select the product by choosing the default configurable product and select configure and choose the product which is out of stock. After selecting the out of stock product a larg red X showed beneath the product Says that the product is out of stock. But the admin was able to make the order for this product.

Note: let say shoe size 43 is out of stock but 42 is in stock, in the grid the shoe 43 product is hidden from the grid but shoe 42 is shown also the default shoe that combines all sizes is shown, so the admin can choose the default shoe and press configure then chose size 43 which is out of stock then he can make the order( here is the problem).

Answer (score 0):

if you go to /vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php to function _prepareCollection and you add

```
$collection->joinField(
            'qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
        );
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('qty', ['neq' => 0]);
```

you should not see any products in the grid who's qty is 0 **But** it would bad practice to write it in here so you have to overwrite this file. With a bit of help from google im sure you will manage.

Comment: I think your method will give the same result as the above extension written above.